# Android webview how to get session data and user authentication?

Tags: android, session, authentication, webview

I face a challenge to make a simple Android app that embeds a website inside a webview. On the first page of the website the user needs to log in in order to access the contents of the site.

My question would be how can I keep the user logged in and extract and save session data, so after he kills the app and starts again the login will no longer be needed. I never worked with webview before and I'm lost here. I guess I can not react to login and logout button clicks, so I don't know how is this possible. Can you provide me with some guidance, how should I do this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having an activity to enter login info and saving in shared prefrences. The insert the info  using evaluate javascript and calling a function to insert login info into form values. Then a function that submits the form. Then if you look at CookiesHandler you should be able to figure out how to get the webview cookies and use that to do more intense stuff.